# Updating gradle wrapper in Unity3D

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, gradle

I'm using Unity3D to build an Android game, but it looks like Unity is using old versions of Gradle. For example it's using Gradle Wrapper 4.6 instead of the latest one 5.0, or at least the previous latest 4.10.2.

I've tried replacing the gradle lib folder in `Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Tools\gradle\lib` with a gradle version from Android Studio, Unity started saying `invalid gradle installation`

**P.S: I've asked this on Unity, but either that place is dead, or not much support**